# What does this Delphi code means? (From the customlistbox example)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I was looking at all the examples shipped with RAD Studio xe6 when I came across the custom listbox example located at

**Object Pascal > FireMonkey Desktop > CustomListBox**

Trying to play with it and see what modifications I could do, I decided that it I wanted to create a for loop that would get the visible or not property for each object. The thing though is that I can't understand what the following line actually means.

```
107| Item.StylesData['visible.OnChange'] := TValue.From<TNotifyEvent>(DoVisibleChange); // set OnChange value
```

It adds an onChange event, but how exactly? What is TNotifyEvent, is that how we tell the compiler to create a new event?

Thanks.

Comment: What event did you pull the second example from?

Comment: You asked two questions. Suppose I can answer one but not the other. What should I do?

Comment: The second code snippet seems to be inside an event, could it be that it is in the body of the onchange event set in the first snippet?

Comment: @David: answer the one you can answer but not the other. ;-)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: SO is based on the concept of "question and answer", not "questions and answers". How do you accept an answer if two separate people each answer a separate question in the same post? Don't encourage incorrect behavior here to a new user, even jokingly. They may not notice the ;-).

Comment: I don't think I encourage any behaviour. I just answered David's question.

Comment: Hey guys, I see now how this is not a good question, I just added those things together because with the little I know I thought that those lines are interlocked in order to provide one functionality and it would be hard for someone to understand one without looking at the others. So what should I do about this question? (Split it, edit it)

Comment: Edit the second question out and put it in a question of its own.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent

Comment: Ok I changed the question to something that will hopefully be more appropriate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think I understand better what is going on now. Still care to write that down as an answer and elaborate a bit more. I am sure it will be more helpful than the embarcadero docwiki for anyone interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FireMonkey styles framework has been designed to be flexible and extensible. It is introduced at the root of the styled control hierarchy, [`TStyledControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TStyledControl). This [article](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Primitive_Controls_and_Styled_Controls) gives a brief introduction and explanation of the philosophy behind the design.

Because the styling framework is designed to support many different types of controls, there is a clear need for flexibility and extensibility. So you see code like this:

```
StylesData['visible.OnChange'] := ...
```

The [`StylesData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TStyledControl.StylesData) property is an [array property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Array_Properties), indexed with a string. It is declared like this:

```
property StylesData[const Index: string]: TValue;
```

The `TValue` type is the modern variant type that is used throughout the RTL. So, we gain flexibility by allowing `StylesData` to hold any kind of object, by means of using a variant type, `TValue`. And we have extensibility by allowing named indices.

So, the control that you are referring to allows you to customise its behaviour when its visibility changes. It does so by checking for a style named `visible.OnChange` that is expected to be of type [`TNotifyEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent). We cannot supply the `TNotifyEvent` directly, we have to wrap it in a `TValue`. And hence the call to `TValue<TNotifyEvent>.From()`.